# Lambda GraphQL endpoint works everywhere except another Lambda endpoint on the same domain

Tags: express, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, apollo, serverless

So I have a lambda graphql endpoint set up at `app.mydomain.com/graphql`

The stack is made up of Apollo running on express, resolved by Sequelize, pointed at an RDS database.

My main web app lambda endpoint is `app.mydomain.com/`, which is made up of express, vue, and the Apollo client. Going forward, I'll call this *the webserver*

With this setup, here are the things that work:

1. Site fetches data when graphql server and webserver are running locally.
2. Site fetches data when webserver is local, but pointed at production graphql endpoint.
3. Production graphql endpoint can fetch data via graphiql playground it serves at app.mydomain.com/graphiql.
4. Production graphql endpoint fetches data from my local machine via `curl`.

HOWEVER. When my webserver is running in production, it cannot fetch data form my graphql endpoint. The headers of the successful graphiql request and the unsuccessful web server request are completely identical, but the former returns HTTP status `200` and data, and the latter returns `502` and no data.

How is this possible? Is there some kind of IAM or VPC setting I need to change to make one Lambda endpoint reach another?

I'm kind of baffled since graphiql and off-domain requests seem to be working fine.

Comment: have you solved this one?
I think the possible reason for this is that the apollo-server-express passes context with `req` as a property while apollo-server-lambda passes context with `event` as a property.